# Invert Slider's minimum and maximum value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-slider

```
Slider(
min: 0,
max: 35,
divisions: 15,
value: _sliderValue.toDouble(),
onChanged: _change1Slider)

void _change1Slider(double e) => setState(() {
        _sliderValue = e;
        print((_sliderValue * base_number).floor() / base_number);
      });
```

I'm using Flutter's Slider and want to invert min and max.

I want 35 to be the value shown on the left and I want 0 to be the value shown on the right.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 35 is greater than 0.  You can't change that.  Perhaps you want a slider that has the high number at the left toward a low number at the right? It doesn't appear to permit that, but nothing stops you from copying the source and making a class like MySlder that reverss the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show your maximum value on the left and your minimum value on the right, change the text direction of the `Slider` to `right to left`.

Do this by:

1. wrapping the `Slider` widget in the [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) widget and
2. specifying the `textDirection` property as [TextDirection.rtl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextDirection.html#rtl).

```dart
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Slider(
    label: _sliderValue.toString(),
    min: 0,
    max: 35,
    divisions: 15,
    value: _sliderValue.toDouble(),
    onChanged: _change1Slider),
),
```

Here's a screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of slider showing the max value on the left and the min value on the right]